# Small projects for improving development

Tags: software-industry, software-development, developer, learning, code

TLDR: **How big and what kind of programming projects do you create just to learn new things as a software developers?**

Recenlty, I realized that due to some legacy projects I worked with, **my programming knowlegde needs a strong refresh** in terms of technolgies and digging into details of how things work. After I started a new job I have access to many different areas like **cloud deployment, kubernetes, mongoDB, Kibana, Jenkins** or **ReactJS** - just to mention a few of them. Of course it is impossible to learn everything at once but my question is about the way of gathering a practical knowledge on such areas in spare time.

**Example**:
I see a configuration of **logback** logging used via Slf4j etc... My first idea is just to write a small CRUD rest application and configure loggers to log to files, database, play with formatters, logging level configuration etc...
Don't you think it is a **waste of time** to spend two or three evenings (or 10 hours) on such **small project** and instead I should use new knowledge in a bigger application?

What approach do you have? **What things do you code in spare time to learn new topics**?

Comment: When learning to program did you start with one large project or a bunch of little ones?

Comment: VTC - this feels like it belongs on one of the Programming SE

Comment: @TheDemonLord agreed off topic here but also too opinion-based for any of the more technical stacks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is different pros and cons to this, depending on what you want to learn, why, what your level is etc. So it is imho impossible to give a concrete general answer in the project size or such. One answer that I can generally give though for such hobby projects to learn something:

**Do whatever you are motivated to do**

It does not make (much) sense to go for projects you are not interested in and don't have fun doing in your spare time just because in theory this and that type of project you could learn more from (unless perhaps you have enough external pressure, e.g. because of exams or concrete work related needs, but then you typically know already what you need to learn). You need all the intrinsic motivation you have to take the most out of it and actually stay engaged.

And since you might not know what you are motivated to do in the long run, evaluate yourself. If you give up on a project without learning something note down the parameters of that project (small project, small thing to learn, big project, totally new language) etc. Same if you take something useful from it. Then after a while you can compare your lists and use as a guide to pick the next one.

Comment: Thanks a lot :)